# AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\blahblahblah\emailsend.py", line 26, in <module>
    msg.attach(MIMEText(file))
  File "E:\blahblahblah\Python 2.7.11\lib\email\mime\text.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.set_payload(_text, _charset)
  File "E:\blahblahblah\Python 2.7.11\lib\email\message.py", line 226, in set_payload
    self.set_charset(charset)
  File "E:\blahblahblah\Python 2.7.11\lib\email\message.py", line 268, in set_charset
    cte(self)
  File "E:\blahblahblah\Python 2.7.11\lib\email\encoders.py", line 73, in encode_7or8bit
    orig.encode('ascii')
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'encode'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```

I've been looking this up a lot but I haven't found an answer.

The only important parts of the code is this:

```html
file = open('newfile.txt')

msg.attach(MIMEText(file))
```

There are other parts but I've debugged it and I get the error at the 'msg.attach(MIMEText(file))' line.

Any help?

Comment: Where did you read that `MIMEText()` can take a file?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I thought the open() would convert it to a string inside the variable.

Comment: Where did you read that `open()` returns text?

Comment: `open()` returns a file object.  https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open.  In python 2 another name for `open()` is `file()`, which is why you should not have a variable named `file`.

Comment: @cdarke thank you for the link. I am relatively new to Python so I assumed it would open a .txt as a string.

Comment: Which language are you familiar with?  Most languages have some sort of open clause (not always called `open` of course), followed by reading (or writing) the file.

Comment: @cdarke I've come from javascript but I haven't used files that much so I didn't really know how they worked.

Comment: Fair enough, take a look at this:  http://www.diveintopython.net/file_handling/file_objects.html

Comment: @cdarke great thank you. I'll take a look when I'n not busy :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MIMEText takes the *content* of the file, not the file object.

```
msg.attach(MIMEText(open("newfile.txt").read()))
```

Comment: thanks it worked. You are missing another closing bracket though. It should be: msg.attach(MIMEText(open("newfile.txt").read()))